# Facebook GRAPH API Photo like count without paging

Tags: facebook-graph-api, count, facebook-like

I'm trying to get like counts for FB pictures. The pictures we are counting the likes for are usually VERY popular so have a big amounts of LIKES.

For example, the " 4 more years" obama picture is the "most liked" on facebook with more than 4 million likes.

The problem is that nowhere in the GRAPH API reponse for that picture do we get the count number, I would have to page through the whole four million likes to get the number... its insane.

https://graph.facebook.com/10151255420886749/likes

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "100004002885259",
         "name": "Camy Doyna"
      },
      {
         "id": "100003495050210",
         "name": "Louzoco de Carvasal"
      },
      {
         "id": "536183064",
         "name": "Emily Brearley"
      },
      {
         "id": "100002742193990",
         "name": "Rosette Gracia Moukengue"
      },
      {
         "id": "100001107540696",
         "name": "Pac\u00f4me Chazelle"
      },
      {
         "id": "100001035425365",
         "name": "Niklas Pulli"
      },
      {
         "id": "100003292089993",
         "name": "Barbara Grimm"
      },
      {
         "id": "642830020",
         "name": "Elin Vinterhed"
      },
      {
         "id": "100000718890127",
         "name": "Katya Katyusha"
      },
      {
         "id": "1644725575",
         "name": "Lara Corti"
      },
      {
         "id": "100002024205882",
         "name": "Garibyan Anna"
      },
      {
         "id": "100002159247248",
         "name": "Marcos Fernando"
      },
      {
         "id": "1725354804",
         "name": "Kevin Burk"
      },
      {
         "id": "1524833123",
         "name": "Roberto TwoHands Bertuccelli"
      },
      {
         "id": "1056165559",
         "name": "Arman Hossain Anand"
      },
      {
         "id": "1052974324",
         "name": "Kathy Johng Shelton"
      },
      {
         "id": "100000254736003",
         "name": "Tina Mosely"
      },
      {
         "id": "595281527",
         "name": "Kim Fontaine-Skronski"
      },
      {
         "id": "100002935725139",
         "name": "Iulian Boxerul"
      },
      {
         "id": "100001450004383",
         "name": "Nora Lachgar"
      },
      {
         "id": "100001859484728",
         "name": "Joan Breen"
      },
      {
         "id": "1802479070",
         "name": "Jan Meyer"
      },
      {
         "id": "1815802454",
         "name": "Gregory Nobre"
      },
      {
         "id": "100002988798465",
         "name": "Aika JU"
      },
      {
         "id": "100003737463206",
         "name": "Ingrid Theiszov\u00e1-Bajusov\u00e1"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/10151255420886749/likes?limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=100003737463206"
   }
}
```

https://graph.facebook.com/10151255420886749

```
{
   "id": "10151255420886749",
   "from": {
      "category": "Politician",
      "name": "Barack Obama",
      "id": "6815841748"
   },
   "name": "Four more years.",
   "picture": "http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/409202_10151255420886749_2117448131_s.jpg",
   "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/409202_10151255420886749_2117448131_n.jpg",
   "height": 478,
   "width": 720,
   "images": [
      {
         "height": 1359,
         "width": 2048,
         "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s2048x2048/409202_10151255420886749_2117448131_n.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 532,
         "width": 800,
         "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/409202_10151255420886749_2117448131_n.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 478,
         "width": 720,
         "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/409202_10151255420886749_2117448131_n.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 398,
         "width": 600,
         "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s600x600/409202_10151255420886749_2117448131_n.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 318,
         "width": 480,
         "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s480x480/409202_10151255420886749_2117448131_n.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 212,
         "width": 320,
         "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s320x320/409202_10151255420886749_2117448131_n.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 119,
         "width": 180,
         "source": "http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/409202_10151255420886749_2117448131_a.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 86,
         "width": 130,
         "source": "http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/409202_10151255420886749_2117448131_s.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 86,
         "width": 130,
         "source": "http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s75x225/409202_10151255420886749_2117448131_s.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151255420886749&set=a.53081056748.66806.6815841748&type=1",
   "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
   "created_time": "2012-11-07T04:15:07+0000",
   "updated_time": "2012-11-07T04:15:07+0000",
   "comments": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12810477",
            "from": {
               "name": "David Carol",
               "id": "100003175318626"
            },
            "message": "BISHOP ZACHARY KAKOBE VERIFIED AIDS HEALING MIRACLES IN HIS MINISTRIES. THIS MINISTRY REGISTERED IN U.S.A IN 2010. WEBSITE: WWW.bishopzacharykakobe.org",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-28T20:00:21+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12811019",
            "from": {
               "name": "Lievin Bangali",
               "id": "1812106678"
            },
            "message": "Barack Obama, Felicitation de votre reelection. Il est grand temps d'agir pour la situation de l'EST de la RD Congo. Merci et courage!",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-28T20:40:28+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12811211",
            "from": {
               "name": "Pamela Aupindi",
               "id": "100004586432226"
            },
            "message": "President Obama is not only a charismatic leader but an obviously passionate man. One can feel the love for his wife through the pic! Amazing",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-28T20:54:40+0000",
            "like_count": 1,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12811850",
            "from": {
               "name": "Ardavan Shafiie",
               "id": "1174217484"
            },
            "message": "graet picture",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-28T21:35:26+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12812793",
            "from": {
               "name": "Samson Anifowose",
               "id": "658496517"
            },
            "message": "All the best!",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-28T22:51:30+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12814187",
            "from": {
               "name": "Yago Costa",
               "id": "100000919886198"
            },
            "message": "isso ae negao !!!",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T00:39:57+0000",
            "like_count": 1,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12814238",
            "from": {
               "name": "Sena Raharja",
               "id": "100004587874401"
            },
            "message": "wow",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T00:43:08+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12814255",
            "from": {
               "name": "Getachew Biratu",
               "id": "100004104261949"
            },
            "message": "Better \u0040 home...!!!",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T00:43:45+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12814350",
            "from": {
               "name": "Bennydictus Ari Setiabudi",
               "id": "714307966"
            },
            "message": "uhuk... lama2 terkikis image seno raharjo... XD",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T00:50:10+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12814615",
            "from": {
               "name": "Sena Raharja",
               "id": "100004587874401"
            },
            "message": "mukanya mirip gua. Ini foto bikin rekor dunia.",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T01:06:44+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12814662",
            "from": {
               "name": "Bennydictus Ari Setiabudi",
               "id": "714307966"
            },
            "message": "beda nasib dikit doang kali y... hehehe... :D",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T01:09:59+0000",
            "like_count": 1,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12814794",
            "from": {
               "name": "Subhash Biradar",
               "id": "100003474405756"
            },
            "message": "    Its better...ha ha ha ha.",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T01:20:35+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12815269",
            "from": {
               "name": "Barbara J. Beverly",
               "id": "1348022951"
            },
            "message": "I am still smiling and happy....such a wonderful day in America.",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T01:51:15+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12815652",
            "from": {
               "name": "Phillip Mason",
               "id": "100001280178407"
            },
            "message": "Makes me want to throw up. The Muslim and his ..........",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T02:17:19+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12815699",
            "from": {
               "name": "Jeremiah Bates",
               "id": "100000912015322"
            },
            "message": "The clown above me is far below me .",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T02:21:04+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12815758",
            "from": {
               "name": "Jeremiah Bates",
               "id": "100000912015322"
            },
            "message": "Sad...Phillip Mason, they have self help tapes, education programs, support groups for uneducated fools such as yourself....",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T02:26:12+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12816036",
            "from": {
               "name": "Romy Christie",
               "id": "100003856980181"
            },
            "message": "To Barbara J Beverly, I completely agree with you, what a Wonderful day for America, long live President Obama, may his next four years leave him a shining place in history! Great charisma and a great orator, I believe that he is doing his utmost with the heavy burden that was put upon his shoulders when he first began... From Romy, British National, Permanent resident in Tokyo Japan.November 29th2012 instant.",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T02:45:35+0000",
            "like_count": 1,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12818055",
            "from": {
               "name": "\u0122in \u01feblsk\u00e5 K\u00e4n\u0115",
               "id": "100001520690200"
            },
            "message": "\u0641\u0649 \u0627\u064a\u0647 \u064a\u0627 \u0648\u0644\u0627\u062f \u0627\u0644.........",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T06:37:20+0000",
            "like_count": 1,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12818064",
            "from": {
               "name": "Cm Amgad",
               "id": "100001979501265"
            },
            "message": "\u0627\u0646\u062a\u0627 \u064a\u0627 \u0639\u0645 \u0628\u0627\u0631\u0627\u0643 \u0627\u0648\u0628\u0627\u0645\u0627",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T06:38:26+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12818067",
            "from": {
               "name": "Cm Amgad",
               "id": "100001979501265"
            },
            "message": "\u0644\u0645\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0630 \u062c\u064a\u0646 \u064a\u062a\u0643\u0644\u0645 \u062a\u0631\u062f \u0639\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u064a\u0627 \u0643\u0633\u0645\u0643",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T06:39:21+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12818275",
            "from": {
               "name": "Denise Mutty Henry",
               "id": "707184927"
            },
            "message": "who is the boss? michele of course",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T07:21:36+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12818295",
            "from": {
               "name": "Steve Muguerza",
               "id": "100001926262266"
            },
            "message": "Dont worry honey I will do as you say and begin down america with the americas helping me they are so so weak we will just send them a check and keep them down like we keep the blacks down and in their place. Keep them poor and uneducated and teach them to rap.",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T07:25:55+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12818637",
            "from": {
               "name": "David Torrens",
               "id": "699130216"
            },
            "message": "So USA votes for the right team after all.  And there was me thinking you might go back to a rather bushy nut.",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T08:48:22+0000",
            "like_count": 1,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12818837",
            "from": {
               "category": "Fictional character",
               "name": "\u0645\u064f\u0640\u0633\u062a\u062d\u064a\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0644 \u0623\u0646\u0640\u0633\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0627\u0643\u064a\u0650 \u0644\u0623\u0646\u0646\u0651\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u064a \u0639\u0627\u064a\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0634\u064c \u0639\u0644\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u064a \u0630\u0643\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0631\u0627\u0643\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u0640\u064a\u0650",
               "id": "101906399977956"
            },
            "message": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/\u0025D9\u002585\u0025D9\u00258F\u0025D8\u0025B3\u0025D8\u0025AA\u0025D8\u0025AD\u0025D9\u00258A\u0025D9\u002580\u0025D9\u002580\u0025D9\u002580\u0025D9\u002580\u0025D9\u002580\u0025D9\u002580\u0025D9\u002584-\u0025D8\u0025A7\u0025D9\u002586\u0025D8\u0025B3\u0025D9\u002580\u0025D9\u002580\u0025D9\u002580\u0025D9\u002580\u0025D9\u002580\u0025D8\u0025A7\u0025D9\u002583\u0025D9\u00258A-\u0025D9\u002584\u0025D8\u0025A3\u0025D9\u002586\u0025D9\u002586\u0025D9\u00258A-\u0025D8\u0025B9\u0025D8\u0025A7\u0025D9\u00258A\u0025D8\u0025B4-\u0025D8\u0025B9\u0025D9\u002584\u0025D9\u00258A-\u0025D8\u0025B0\u0025D9\u002583\u0025D8\u0025B1\u0025D8\u0025A7\u0025D9\u002583\u0025D9\u00258A/101906399977956?ref=hl",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T09:36:54+0000",
            "like_count": 0,
            "user_likes": false
         },
         {
            "id": "10151255420886749_12819093",
            "from": {
               "name": "Mojisola Otu",
               "id": "100000238597273"
            },
            "message": "All the Best.\nMy family prays for yours.",
            "can_remove": false,
            "created_time": "2012-11-29T10:41:24+0000",
            "like_count": 1,
            "user_likes": false
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/10151255420886749/comments?limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=10151255420886749_12819093"
      }
   },
   "likes": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "100004002885259",
            "name": "Camy Doyna"
         },
         {
            "id": "100003495050210",
            "name": "Louzoco de Carvasal"
         },
         {
            "id": "536183064",
            "name": "Emily Brearley"
         },
         {
            "id": "100002742193990",
            "name": "Rosette Gracia Moukengue"
         },
         {
            "id": "100001107540696",
            "name": "Pac\u00f4me Chazelle"
         },
         {
            "id": "100001035425365",
            "name": "Niklas Pulli"
         },
         {
            "id": "100003292089993",
            "name": "Barbara Grimm"
         },
         {
            "id": "642830020",
            "name": "Elin Vinterhed"
         },
         {
            "id": "100000718890127",
            "name": "Katya Katyusha"
         },
         {
            "id": "1644725575",
            "name": "Lara Corti"
         },
         {
            "id": "100002024205882",
            "name": "Garibyan Anna"
         },
         {
            "id": "100002159247248",
            "name": "Marcos Fernando"
         },
         {
            "id": "1725354804",
            "name": "Kevin Burk"
         },
         {
            "id": "1524833123",
            "name": "Roberto TwoHands Bertuccelli"
         },
         {
            "id": "1056165559",
            "name": "Arman Hossain Anand"
         },
         {
            "id": "1052974324",
            "name": "Kathy Johng Shelton"
         },
         {
            "id": "100000254736003",
            "name": "Tina Mosely"
         },
         {
            "id": "595281527",
            "name": "Kim Fontaine-Skronski"
         },
         {
            "id": "100002935725139",
            "name": "Iulian Boxerul"
         },
         {
            "id": "100001450004383",
            "name": "Nora Lachgar"
         },
         {
            "id": "100001859484728",
            "name": "Joan Breen"
         },
         {
            "id": "1802479070",
            "name": "Jan Meyer"
         },
         {
            "id": "1815802454",
            "name": "Gregory Nobre"
         },
         {
            "id": "100002988798465",
            "name": "Aika JU"
         },
         {
            "id": "100003737463206",
            "name": "Ingrid Theiszov\u00e1-Bajusov\u00e1"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/10151255420886749/likes?limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=100003737463206"
      }
   }
}
```

Doing something like adding a paging limit parameter with a ridiculously high value is way too slow... is there a way to get the count number straight up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can retrieve this information via the [`photo` FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo):

```
select like_info from photo where object_id = 10151255420886749;
```

Returns:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "like_info": {
        "can_like": true, 
        "like_count": 4444816, 
        "user_likes": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sure, $result = FB.api('/fql?q=select like_info from photo where object_id = 10151255420886749');
echo $result;

Comment: @Igy can you plz provide the photo-count of a user for graph api,since i am not using fql

Comment: The answer immediately below mine includes that information

Answer (score 11):

You might also try /likes?summary=1 to get the "summary/total_count" added to your result, so

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10151255420886749/likes?summary=1
```

returns:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "100004351206696",
      "name": "Marcos Nones"
    },
    {
      "id": "100002271852907",
      "name": "Kishor Ray"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "MTU4NTQ1MzczMw==",
      "before": "MTAwMDA0MzUxMjA2Njk2"
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/10151255420886749/likes?summary=1&limit=25&after=MTU4NTQ1MzczMw%3D%3D"
  },
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 4434080
  }
}
```

Comment: You can add `&limit=1` so the result set has minimum rows.