# Get likes count of photos uploaded from app

Tags: php, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app i upload a photo to the facebook account of the user, after the login i use this code:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                            parameters:params
                            HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                         id result,
                                         NSError *error)
```

It works and it return me the id of the just uploaded picture, (782585955138999 for example,this is a fake number). Now i have to retrive the total like number that for this photo. I have found this answer (i don't wanna use fql, it seems that will be deprecated soon)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17697750/3057259

The result will be something like :

https://graph.facebook.com/782585955138999/likes?summary=1

This call with my id return :

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100
   }
}
```

My photo is public as the obama photo linked in the answer (the example obama graph call works for me) ... What's the difference? How i can retrive the likes count of a photo?

Comment: you can find photo like using like this albumid/photos/photoid (ex.-1376214422675581/photos/1382251658738524 ). try this i this its useful for you.

Comment: it returns a null 'data' array

Comment: i think you does`t get require permission for access data . please check .

Comment: ok but why i can see working this call for obama picture and for my not? Also my photo is 'public'