# Can you pull the # of facebook likes on a picture?

Tags: facebook, photos

I wanted to add a history of the number of likes a facebook photo has.  Does facebook allow developers to pull the number of likes a user's photos get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API - Get like count on page/group photos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984526/facebook-graph-api-get-like-count-on-page-group-photos)

Comment: Are you particularly interested in the history of the number of Likes? That is not possible. See this edge for what you can get: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/likes/