# Get Facebook page/profile visitor's count on Android

Tags: android, facebook-page, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook

I have been researching a lot but could not figure out if there is a way to get the Facebook page or profile visits (count) programmatically. I don't need any further information other than the count.

Been developing an android app and I need to show a rating for my page on the app. I don't want the facebook rating, I have developed my own equation for which I need the visit count.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984526/facebook-graph-api-get-like-count-on-page-group-photos) may help you.

Comment: Thanks, but it is totally different than my requirement. I do know how to get likes of images; I want to know my page visits or post visits. I found this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights) but it's difficult to understand response.